# conflict with search module

Tags: 7, forms, search

I have a problem about conflict a custom search form with search module.
in custom form  custom search interface provided ,the codes of form and submit show in below,
when  the search module is disable this form work correctly but when the search module this is not work and only just redirect to /search/node.
I don't find out where is the problem,any body can help me about this problem ?

```
function floristdev_search_filter_form($form, &$form_state) {

    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
                            ->propertyCondition('vid', 2)
                            ->propertyOrderBy('weight', 'ASC');
    $result = $query->execute();    
    $cats = entity_load('taxonomy_term', array_keys($result['taxonomy_term']));
    $flower_types['All'] = t('Choose by Category');
    foreach($cats as $index => $cat)
        $flower_types[$index] = t($cat->name);  
    $form['field_flower_type_cat_tid'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => $flower_types,
        '#default_value' => $_GET['field_flower_type_cat_tid'],
    );


    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
                            ->propertyCondition('vid', 3)
                            ->propertyOrderBy('weight', 'ASC');
    $result = $query->execute();    
    $cats = entity_load('taxonomy_term', array_keys($result['taxonomy_term']));
    $ocassion['All'] = t('Choose by Occasion');
    foreach($cats as $index => $cat)
        $ocassion[$index] = t($cat->name);
    $form['field_ocassion_tid'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => $ocassion,
    '#default_value' => $_GET['field_ocassion_tid'],
    );


    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
                            ->propertyCondition('vid', 6)
                            ->propertyOrderBy('weight', 'ASC');
    $result = $query->execute();    
    $cats = entity_load('taxonomy_term', array_keys($result['taxonomy_term']));
    $colors['All'] = t('Choose by Color');
    foreach($cats as $index => $cat)
        $colors[$index] = t($cat->name);
    $form['field_color_tid'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => $colors,
    '#default_value' => $_GET['field_color_tid'],
    );

    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
                            ->propertyCondition('vid', 4)
                            ->propertyOrderBy('weight', 'ASC');
    $result = $query->execute();    
    $cats = entity_load('taxonomy_term', array_keys($result['taxonomy_term']));
    $flower_names['All'] = t('Choose by Flower');
    foreach($cats as $index => $cat)
        $flower_names[$index] = t($cat->name);
    $form['field_flower_name_cat_tid'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => $flower_names,
        '#default_value' => $_GET['field_flower_name_cat_tid'],
    );

    $form['price_range'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#options' => array(
            'All' => t('Choose by price'),
            '1' => t('Less than $25.00'),
            '2' => t('$25.00 to $50.00'),
            '3' => t('$50.00 to $75.00'),
            '4' => t('$75.00 to $100.00'),
            '5' => t('$100.00 to $150.00'),
            '6' => t('Over $150.00'),
        ),
    '#default_value' => $_GET['price_range'],
    );


    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Search'),
    );

    return $form;
}

function floristdev_search_filter_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $query = array(
            'field_flower_type_cat_tid'=> $form_state['values']['field_flower_type_cat_tid'],
            'field_ocassion_tid'=> $form_state['values']['field_ocassion_tid'],
            'field_color_tid'=> $form_state['values']['field_color_tid'],
            'field_flower_name_cat_tid'=> $form_state['values']['field_flower_name_cat_tid'],
            'price_range'=> $form_state['values']['price_range'],
            );


    $form_state['redirect'] = url('search', 
        array('absolute' => true, 
        'query' => $query,
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: You are redirect form submission to `search` page and same url `search` exist in `search` module, so you are getting error. Please update your `$form_state['redirect']` with correct url.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola you right I dont notice that this menu exist, this is not my code I just debug it for a company and I did not wrote it. tnx. your mention help me to fix it.

Comment: It my pleasure to help you.

Comment: I have also added this as answer, so it will help future user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are redirecting `form` submission to `search` page and same url `search` exist in `search` module, so both module are conflicting with each other.

You should use a different URL for your module or you should alter `menu callback` for `search` page with your function.